# Append same randint string to Parent as well as child in data frame using list comprehension

Tags: pandas, random, conditional-statements, parent-child, list-comprehension

I have a function that generates a unique 6 digit string using randint for a given 14 digit string as follows:

```
import random as r
from random import randint 

srng='60817409470000' #This is just an example of the input string


def un_Gen(srng):
    ''' Takes in 14 digit string and assigns a unique 6 digit string using randint and concatenates wiht 11th index '''
    if len(srng) >= 13:
        unid = str(randint(100000,999999)) #generate unique 6 digit string 
        ud = unid + '-00' + srng[11]       #concatenate 6 digit string to child rank at 11th index  
    else:
        ud = 'NA'                         #Exceptional handeling for invalid strings

    return ud
```

So for ex:

```
un_Gen('60817408440000')

Out[288]:
'217417-000'
```

I would like to apply this function to the ['UWI'] column in my df in the following way:

I want to generate a new column in my df in such a way that it assigns the new string generated by my un_Gen function to the rows assigned a Parent value (as it is indicated by the ['Parent'] column.

When it comes to any child values (which share the first 10 digit values) , I want the same 6 digit randint number assigned to the child but the string after the dash should have the child rank, which can be indicated by the ['Rank'] column.

So for example, in the attached df image I want a new column for the the highlighted rows in yellow to have the same random 6 digits but the last 3 should reference the child rank.

```
'60817408440000'--> '217417-000'
'60817408440100'--> '217417-001'
'60817408440200'--> '217417-002'
'60817408440300'--> '217417-003'
'60817408440400'--> '217417-004'
```

Currently I'm trying to achieve this using list comprehension and conditional statements in the following matter:

```
dfcat['BUI'] = [un_Gen(str(i)) for i in dfcat['UWI'] if dfcat['Parent'][i] == True ]
```

The issue that I'm having is that

1)I'm getting the following error

```
IndexError: index out of bounds
```

2) Right now my code generates randint 6 digit strings for ALL rows in df. How do I code it in such a way that the children end up with the same 6-digit string as the parent. I already have a column that displays the first 10 digits as the ['Family'], I want the code to use the same rand 6 digits for all the family members.

I look forward to any suggestions/solutions/help and thank you for taking the time to look over this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1VEC.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach, it's not ideal, nor does it directly provide what you are looking.
First note if you have control over u_Gen() then I would suggest a rewrite within it. The answer below assumes you do not have control:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random as r
from random import randint 

def un_Gen(srng):
    ''' Takes in 14 digit string and assigns a unique 6 digit string using randint and concatenates wiht 11th index '''
    if len(srng) >= 13:
        unid = str(randint(100000,999999)) #generate unique 6 digit string 
        ud = unid + '-00' + srng[11]       #concatenate 6 digit string to child rank at 11th index  
    else:
        ud = 'NA'                         #Exceptional handeling for invalid strings

    return ud  

# first some sample data:
df = pd.DataFrame([60817408440000,60817408440100,60817408440200,60817408440300,60817408440400,70817408440000,70817408440100],columns=['base'])

#now a process using helper columns to attain the result, these can be dropped at the end.
df['family'] = np.floor(df['base'] /1000)*1000
df['family'] =df['family'].astype(np.int64).astype(str)
df['rnk']  = df.groupby('family')['base'].rank()


    base            family          rnk
0   60817408440000  60817408440000  1.0
1   60817408440100  60817408440000  2.0
2   60817408440200  60817408440000  3.0
3   60817408440300  60817408440000  4.0
4   60817408440400  60817408440000  5.0
5   70817408440000  70817408440000  1.0
6   70817408440100  70817408440000  2.0


df['family_mapped'] = df[['rnk','family']].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x['rnk'] !=1 else un_Gen(x['family']),axis=1)


df['family_mapped'] = df.groupby('family')['family_mapped'].ffill()
df[['parent','temp_child']] =  df['family_mapped'].str.split('-',expand=True) 
df['temp_child'] = df['base'].map(lambda x: str(x)[-3:])
df['BUI']  = df[['parent','temp_child']].apply(lambda x: str(x['parent']) + '-' + str(x['temp_child']),axis=1)

    base            family          rnk family_mapped   parent  temp_child  BUI
0   60817408440000  60817408440000  1.0 217100-000     217100   000         217100-000
1   60817408440100  60817408440000  2.0 217100-000     217100   100         217100-100
2   60817408440200  60817408440000  3.0 217100-000     217100   200         217100-200
3   60817408440300  60817408440000  4.0 217100-000     217100   300         217100-300
4   60817408440400  60817408440000  5.0 217100-000     217100   400         217100-400
5   70817408440000  70817408440000  1.0 834075-000     834075   000         834075-000
6   70817408440100  70817408440000  2.0 834075-000     834075   100         834075-100
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very close to what i'm looking for. However, the groupby('column_a')['column_b'].ffill() is not working as it is assigning different unique 6 digits to the same family members.

Comment: the lambda in the previous line: apply(lambda x: np.nan if x['rnk'] !=1 else un_Gen(x['family']),axis=1) should have made them null then the ffill() would work

Comment: happy to chat off line and get the answer you need then tailor the question and answer so it provides a useful technique for others who look into it.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate that, what do you use to communicate?

Comment: No i did not, you can't dm here but I found out there is a chat. Nm, I can't join it yet.